# Ng2 pagination- template error with ngFor

Tags: angular

I am doing simple pagination with angular2 ng2-pagination as follows:

```
div class="col s12 m6" *ngFor="#analytic of _sessionAnalyticsService.useranalytics  | paginate: { itemsPerPage: 4, currentPage: p }; #i=index">

          {{analytic}}
    </div>
    <pagination-controls (pageChange)="p = $event" #api></pagination-controls>
```

Here the above part in div is working fine and getting the records according to the specified items per page.

But pagination-controls tag is throwing following error:
EXCEPTION: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'ngFor' since it isn't a known native property ("

```
    <li [class.current]="getCurrent() === page.value" [ERROR ->]*ngFor="let page of pages">
        <a (click)="setCurrent(page.value)" *ngIf="getCurrent() !== p"): PaginationControlsCmp@16:58
```

Can't bind to 'ngForPage' since it isn't a known native property ("

```
    <li [class.current]="getCurrent() === page.value" [ERROR ->]*ngFor="let page of pages">
        <a (click)="setCurrent(page.value)" *ngIf="getCurrent() !== p"): PaginationControlsCmp@16:58
```

Property binding ngFor not used by any directive on an embedded template ("

```
    [ERROR ->]<li [class.current]="getCurrent() === page.value" *ngFor="let page of pages">
        <a (click)="): PaginationControlsCmp@16:8
```

Property binding ngForPage not used by any directive on an embedded template ("

```
    [ERROR ->]<li [class.current]="getCurrent() === page.value" *ngFor="let page of pages">
        <a (click)="): PaginationControlsCmp@16:8
```

Please help.

Comment: What version of angular do you use?

Comment: Does changing #analytic to "let analytic..." make a difference? On this line  *ngFor="#analytic of _sessionAnalyticsService.useranalytics  ?

Comment: I am using angular version 3.6.0., npm version 3.6.0. and node version 5.7.0.  And #analytic or "let analytic" doesn't make any difference. I tried the both.